# Data provider must return Object[][] or Iterator<Object[]>

Tags: maven, iterator, dataprovider

i have this error "Data provider must return Object[][] or Iterator<Object[]>"
I use IntelliJ, maven, Java 11
Also, I have a problem with parsing JSON documents(related to byte codes), so, maybe it's related with  "Data provider must return..." error

Can you check my code and help me, please

```
package de.cardetecktive.app.model;

import com.google.common.base.Supplier;
import de.cardetecktive.app.ApplicationBaseTest;
import de.cardetecktive.app.cars.Makes;
import de.cardetecktive.app.cars.Models.Model;
import de.cardetecktive.app.enums.Provider;
import de.cardetecktive.app.steps.MakeModelSteps;
import de.cardetecktive.app.utils.CastUtils;
import io.qameta.allure.Feature;
import org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

@Feature("[BE] Application car makes and models by provider")
public class ProviderCarModelsTest extends ApplicationBaseTest {

@Autowired
private MakeModelSteps makeModelSteps;

@DataProvider
public Iterator<Object> carModelsFromMobileDe() {
    return CastUtils.cast(makeModelSteps.requestMakesFromProvider(Provider.MOBILEDEW).iterator(), Object.class);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "carModelsFromMobileDe",
        description = "Client should have the same set of car models for each make as in MOBILEDEW provider")
public void carModelsShouldBeEqualToMobileDeProviderModelsList(final Makes.Make make) {
    modelsAssert(Provider.MOBILEDEW, make);
}

@DataProvider
public Iterator<Object> carModelsFromAutoscout() {
    return CastUtils.cast(makeModelSteps.requestMakesFromProvider(Provider.AUTOSCOUT).iterator(), Object.class);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "carModelsFromAutoscout",
        description = "Client should have the same set of car models for each make as in AUTOSCOUT provider")
public void carModelsShouldBeEqualToAutoscoutProviderModelsList(final Makes.Make make) {
    modelsAssert(Provider.AUTOSCOUT, make);
}
```